# Adding a integer at the end of an string in Python

Tags: python, string, integer

I need to generate a random IP address that starts with "192.168.0." so basically I just need to generate a random number between 0 and 255 and add to the end of this string, but the problem is that I don't know how to merge a integer and a string.

That's my code so far:

```
import random

x=random.randint(0,255)
randIP = '192.168.0.'
randIP.append(x)
print randIP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `+=` operator for appending, but you'll need to convert `x` to a string first using `str`:

```
import random

x=random.randint(0,255)
randIP = '192.168.0.'
randIP += str(x)
print randIP
```

Answer (score 4):

In general, don't use `operator.add` (e.g. `+`) to deal with strings. There's nothing particularly wrong with it, but it's *good practice* to use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) instead.

Try this instead:

```
last_octet = random.randint(0,255) # please use descriptive var names
IP_format = "{}.{}.{}.{}"
IP = IP_format.format(192,168,0,last_octet)
```

Your approach won't work because you're using `append` on a string. `append` is (generally considered to be) a method for a `list` to add to itself. If you'd like to use that method, you could do:

```
last_octet = random.randint(0,255)
IP_list = [192,168,0]
IP_list.append(last_octet) # IP_list is now [192,168,0,<random number>]
IP = ".".join(map(str,IP_list))
```

In that last line I use a combination of two functions you likely don't know about.

- `map` takes two arguments, the first is a function (in this case `str`, e.g. `str(192) --> "192"`) and the second is an iterable (in this case the `list` `IP_list`, but iterables are anything you can use a `for` loop on). It applies the function you give it to every element in the iterable, and leaves you with a DIFFERENT iterable in Python3 called a `map` object. In Python2, it returned a `list`.
- `".".join` is explicitly calling `str.join`. It accepts an iterable as an argument (see above), and puts the `str` between each element of the iterable. `".".join(["192","168","0","255"])` gives you `"192.168.0.255"`. This is possibly most often used by its alias in `os.path`, `os.path.join` which takes a set of arguments and puts the local path separator between each one, e.g. `os.path.join("C:","Program Files","AdamSmith","locale","en-US","docs.html")` would give you a string on Windows that's `"C:\Program Files\AdamSmith\locale\en-US\docs.html"` and on *nix that's `C:/Program Files/AdamSmith/locale/en-US/docs.html"`

Answer (score 1):

Try different approach: [formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). It may look like that:

```
import random

x=random.randint(0,255)
randIP = '192.168.0.%s' % x
print randIP
```

Comment: If it's an `int`, use `%d`, not `%s`. (Not my downvote, though.)

Comment: [string interpolation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) is not recommended since [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) provides the same benefits with greater functionality.

Comment: @AdamSmith Just because it provides greater functionality in general does not make it better in a simple case like this where the greater functionality is not required at all.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers under the [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) docs, "This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the % formatting described in [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) in new code." The only exception of course being if OP is working in Python2 before 2.6, in which case `str.format` is not available. Other than that -- why or how is string interpolation not objectively worse than `str.format`?

Comment: Mea culpa - this snippet is just an example, I provided link to wider description of topic.

Comment: @AdamSmith Fair point. Though to address your last question, for one thing string interpolation has shorter syntax and can thus be more readable in the simple cases. This being a simple case, I'd still prefer it over `.format`. It's also not objectively worse *in this case* because the results are equivalent.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers I can respect that. I still prefer `if type(item) is list` over `isinstance(item,list)` for the same reasons, even though it is objectively worse in ALL cases :).